# maven build fails returns execution is : '127'

Tags: maven, maven-2, exec-maven-plugin

I am trying to rename an artifact using exec-maven-plugin. (I don't want to use antrun plugin as I am using that for a different purpose in the same phase and goal.)

Plugin in pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>some-execution</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <executable>mv "${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-myapp.jar" "${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.app"</executable>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

It fails to rename the artifact and gives below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:exec (some-execution) on project cep: Result of /bin/sh -c cd /home/XYZ/workspace/myapp/solutions/cep && "mv "/home/XYZ/workspace/myapp/solutions/cep/target/cep-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-myapp.jar" "/home/XYZ/workspace/myapp/solutions/cep/target/cep-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.app"" **execution is: '127'**. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:exec (some-execution) on project cep: Result of /bin/sh -c cd /home/XYZ/workspace/myapp/solutions/cep && "mv "/home/XYZ/workspace/myapp/solutions/cep/target/cep-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-myapp.jar" "/home/XYZ/workspace/myapp/solutions/cep/target/cep-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.app"" execution is: '127'.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Result of /bin/sh -c cd /home/XYZ/workspace/myapp/solutions/cep && "mv "/home/XYZ/workspace/myapp/solutions/cep/target/cep-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-myapp.jar" "/home/XYZ/workspace/myapp/solutions/cep/target/cep-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.app"" execution is: '127'.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
```

DEBUG Log :

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:exec from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@762589c3]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:exec' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = /home/XYZ/workspace/myapp/solutions/cep
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathScope = compile
[DEBUG]   (f) executable = mv "/home/XYZ/workspace/myapp/solutions/cep/target/cep-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-myapp.jar" "/home/XYZ/workspace/myapp/solutions/cep/target/cep-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.app"
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.myco:cep:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/XYZ/workspace/myapp/solutions/cep/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@2b46c61f
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] /bin/sh: 1: mv /home/XYZ/workspace/myapp/solutions/cep/target/cep-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-myapp.jar /home/XYZ/workspace/myapp/solutions/cep/target/cep-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.app: **not found**
```

From these log, I am sure something is missing but I am unable to find out what. My OS is ubuntu `/bin/sh` is available. `ls` also lists the artifact at the specified location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!
I was doing it wrong. The `<executable>` tag is supposed to have the command only. The arguments will be defined under `<arguments>`.

Please see the updated plugin definition:

```
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
            <id>some-execution</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            <configuration>
                    <executable>mv</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-myapp.jar</argument>
                                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.app</argument>
                            </arguments>
            </configuration>
     </execution>
   </executions>
  </plugin>
```